# Add UILabel Under UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that shows images, similar to cover art, or iBooks.  I would like for it to show the title of the audio clip underneath the UIImageView.  I have in my MainWindow.xib a View Controller with a UICollectionView inside it.  I also built a NibCell.xib for the cell itself.  In the Cell, I have a UIImageView that fills up all but the bottom 30 px of the cell.  In this area I add a UILabel.  I give the UIImageView a tag of 100 and UILabel a tag of 200, and in my code I put:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *titleLabel = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     UILabel *titleLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];

           NSString *thearticleImage = entry.articleImage;
               [titleLabel setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"]];

        [titleLabel2 setText:entry.articleTitle];
        return cell;
}
```

However, no matter how the cell is set up in NibCell.xib, it makes the UIImageView fill the entire cell, and adds the UILabel on top of it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add your UILabel to cell's contentview

```
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)];
title.tag = 200;
[cell.contentView addSubview:title];
```