# UIImageView filling entire UICollectionView cell

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView displaying a horizontal layout of images. Under each image, I'm displaying a label. In the storyboard, I've extended the height of the cell so that the label will be displayed underneath the cell. I've also set the height of the UIImageView in storyboard to be 20pts less than the cell. However, no matter what I do, the images take up the entire cell and the label is displayed on top of the image. Should I be setting the size of the imageview elsewhere? I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104840/add-uilabel-under-uicollectionview-cell) which I thought would help since it's basically, identical, but the solution did not help me.

Here is my code...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; // string value identifier for cell reuse
    ImageViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

    NSString *myPatternString = [self.imageNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(CellWidth, 20);
    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width/2, cell.bounds.size.height-labelSize.height, cell.bounds.size.width, labelSize.height)];
    testLabel.text = myPatternString;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:testLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work for you, but I do this will a subclass of UIView which contains two subviews -- a UIImageView for the image and a UILabel for the label.  Here is the essence of that subclass below (don't be bothered by the rounding of bottoms; in some areas I need the bottoms to be rounded, in others I don't).  I just add this subview to the contentView of the cell.  Don't know if it helps you but here it is.  BTW, imageView is a class variable here but you might define it as a property.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withImage:(UIImage *)img withLabel:(NSString *)lbl roundBottoms:(BOOL)roundBottoms;
    {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height-25.0f)];

        if (roundBottoms)
        {
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: imageView.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){12.0, 12.}].CGPath;
            imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        }

        [imageView setImage:img];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;   // default

        [self addSubview:imageView];

        UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, frame.size.height - 25.0f, frame.size.width, 25.0f)];
        label.text = lbl;
        labelText = lbl;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;  
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.50f;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.tag = imageItem; // 101
        [self addSubview:label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have another version of it I use where I calculate the height of the label based on the overall frame height that is passed in.  In this one, the cell sizes are static so the label heights can be as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think that's a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do. There must be a very simple way to modify what I already have to make the imageview not fill more than the size I've set. I will play around with your suggestion though.